# How to delete a file created by a Shiny app when the ssession closes

Tags: r, shiny

I generate and display a flextable in a Shiny app and want to place it in a PDF. The only available method is to convert the flextable object to a PNG then place the PNG in the PDF. For each PNG file I assign a filename including a date-time stamp to make it unique between sessions. This file name is saved in a reactiveValue.

When the user is finished and the session is closed, how can I delete the file? If I do not I will pile up extraneous files. I cannot use onSessionEnded() because the reactive values are all gone when the browser is closed. I cannot generalize using a pattern because other users have files with a similar name. I have to delete these PNG files specifically.

Any ideas?

onSessionEnded code that does not work:

```
observe({
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    unlink(c(values$fnameSummary))
    unlink(c(values$fnameLike))
    unlink(c(values$fnameRisk1))
  })
})
```

This produces the following error:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not 
allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something 
that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    33: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    32: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    31: $.reactivevalues
    30: $
    29: unlink
    28: callback [C:\Users\jch1748\Documents\Projects\W2017010 - Combined Risk Tool\testing/server.R#2790]
     1: runApp
```

maybe a working example will help?

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
tsts <- reactiveValues()
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })

   observe({
     tsts$fname <- "AAA.txt"
     write(input$bins, file=tsts$fname)
   })

    onSessionEnded(function() {
     cat("Session Ended\n")
     unlink(tsts$fname)
     }) 
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe use `tempfile` ?

Comment: pdf files in rmarkdown cannot read from anywhere but the apps directory.  I have researched this extensively - there can be no relative file paths in the pdf.  So if I put the png in the temp folder (which I have tried) the pdf cannot find it. unless I use a hard file reference.  That does not work on a Shiny server though.

Comment: Tried `onStop`?

Comment: Doesn't onStop require an actionButton?  If someone closes the window and does not press the button, then the files are left behind, correct?

Comment: Regardless, using the basic onStop implementatio gives the same error as above

Comment: Hi Joe! I wonder have you solved the problem at the end? I'm encountering the exact same problem and I want to find a method to delete the pdf on session end.

Comment: Yes I did.  I will add the code shortly

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to dynamically serve images and pdf files for download in a shiny app. Therefore the files need to be placed within the *www*-directory which makes the use of *tempdir* impossible. Additionally, the created files needed to be deleted after the app stops. I solved the problem with the following code:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
  system(paste("rm -f", PathToFile))
})
```

Comment: As highlighted by fennel, this answer could lead to devastating effects in the case there is no `PathToFile` in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use reactiveValues. Please see:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fname <- "AAA.txt"
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    
    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
  
  observe({
    write(input$bins, file=fname)
  })
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    cat("Session Ended\n")
    unlink(fname)
  }) 
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```